# How can I use a relative range in an excel function

Tags: excel, function

newbie with advance excel here. :)

I'm looking for a solution how to use dynamic or relative range with the expression I came up with. I have this excel sheet with multiple columns, but I only need to check 4 columns for info. The sheet has like 1000 rows and growing, and I need to go through each row and check for blank cells in each row. Obviously dragging the cell with my formula using the mouse automatically updates the cell reference on the expression. However, I'm going to use the expression in an automation tool where it looks one row at a time and captures the value into another "array" or "collection" variable.

```
Col A       B    C    D
Student1    7    8    0
Student2    2    1    2
Student3            
Student4    1    0    2
Student5                
Student6    8    2    4
Student7                
Student8    3    1    2





I have this excel expression
=IF(AND(A2 <> "", A3<>"", A4<>""),A1,"empty")

Expected results should be like the below and placed in another Sheet (Same workbook)
Student3
Student5
Student7

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Have you try using {} as array condition? like =IF(AND(A2 <> {"","Yes","No"}, A3<>"", A4<>""),A1,"empty")

Comment: "I'm going to use the expression in an automation tool" - need more info on exactly what you mean by this.

Comment: @TimWilliams - The automation tool is called Blueprism. It has an Excel Action stage to copy a cell reference value and paste it on a range. The approach I'm thinking is to have an excel expression that can automatically update the cell reference location on its own (relative to the row) so that it can capture the value on the left A Column in reference to the row location. :)
I hope I've explained it clear somehow.

Comment: @PeicongChen 

In the example I shared. I'm looking for the expression to automatically update its row reference when I put it on a certain Cell. 

for example; I pasted the below expression on Cell F999, 
=IF(AND(B1 <> "", C1<>"", D1<>""),A1,"empty") 

the cell reference on the expression should get updated accordingly to A999 as follows 
=IF(AND(B999 <> "", C999<>"", D999<>""),A999,"empty")

Comment: When you try to copy, don't copy the text formula, "=if(A1=" ", "",""), instead, copy the cell so that it will trigger Range.Autofill to update cell reference accordingly.

Comment: @PeicongChen 
    Okay, I tried what you said and the cells get updated accordingly to the row reference. :) I believe this should work for me. Thanks a lot!